# How to get a Tag in Google Tag Manager to trigger on Drupal generated pages only

Tags: drupal, google-tag-manager

I have a website that contains drupal CMS and a lot of other floating/landing page that are not generated by Drupal.
All the pages are sharing the same Google Tag Manager container. 
Recently there is a new tag that only needs to trigger on Drupal pages only.
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do this but you need to understand the general concept first before deciding on the exact route to take.

1. Find a unique way to identify your Drupal page and/or your non-Drupal pages
2. Create a trigger in GTM that can detect this unique property
3. Fire your tag using this trigger

So, what are the ways to find uniqueness between your Drupal and non-Drupal?  Here's a few suggestions:

1. persistent URL structure (e.g. are your landing pages on a sub domain?)
2. Unique HTML element on every drupal or landing page
3. Unique class on every drupal or landing page
4. Unique javascript variable populated on drupal or landing pages